# What is a good application of std::vector::data?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

So my friend and I were looking at the `std::vector` class the other day and noticed that you can use the function `std::vector::data` to retrieve a pointer to the internal array in c++11.  Intuitively this seems somewhat redundant as you can access/update the contents of the internal array using the `[]` on the vector anyway.

It just seems like bad practice to me to "stick your hand into" an STL container.

Anyway, there must be some good applications of it.  So my question is, what are those applications?

Thanks!

Reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/

Comment: Interop with C libraries/API.

Comment: And yes, you can use `&v[0]` for the same purpose, but it's just butt-ugly. `v.data()` is much easier to parse for a reader.

Answer (score 3):

For example if you need to pass the data to a function that only takes a pointer. OpenGL for example has a bunch of them (`glBufferData` for example). `std::vector` makes the memory management easy, so it's a good choice instead for a container instead of managing the memory oneself and potentially leaking it somewhere. It's not meant that you mutate the vectors content through the returned pointer, but rathe read it and/or pass it to functions expecting a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

One example I can think of is to convert stl vector to [Eigen Array](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>

using namespace Eigen;

int main(){
  std::vector<int> my_vec {1,2,3,4};

  Array<int, 4, 1> my_array(my_vec.data());

  std::cout << my_array << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good application of `std::vector::data` is interfacing with C APIs or legacy codebases that do not understand C++ containers but require a raw pointer access to an array.

For example, consider a C library function expecting a pointer to an array of integers:

```
int sum(const int* data, size_t size)
```

Here, you can pass a `std::vector` to the function like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int result = sum(vec.data(), vec.size());
```